# consolidating foreach command

Tags: foreach, tcl

```
foreach old_cellname $old_cell_full_name {
echo $old_cellname >> origin.txt}
foreach origin $cell_origin {
echo $origin >> origin.txt} 
foreach new_cellname $new_cell_full_name {
echo $new_cellname >> origin.txt}
```

Using the above code I am able to get the output in the origin.txt as old cell names followed by their origin numbers followed by the new cell names. But i want my output as rows ie old cell name its origin and new cell name. Is it possible to make these changes? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If the lists are of the same length and match up sensibly, yes, of course. Just use a multi-list `foreach`:

```
foreach old $old_cell_full_name origin $cell_origin new $new_cell_full_name {
    # echo isn't a standard Tcl command, but I guess this ought to work
    echo "$old\t$origin\t$new" >> origin.txt
}
```

I assume tab-separated will do. It's pretty convenient since it lets you import the data into a spreadsheet easily. If you prefer commas, use `,` instead of `\t`.

Comment: If the lists don't match up, you'll probably get gibberish. ;-)

Comment: The reason `echo` works is because Roger did a `package requires Tclx`